# What is a good ergonomic mouse that is not vertical?

Tags: mice, ergonomics

I have been using a [contour mouse](http://ergo.contour-design.com/ergonomic-mouse/contour-mouse) for some time now. It is an ergonomic mouse, however it looks like this:

[image]

I find the angle of my hand when using the mouse to be perfect. Vertical or horizontal mice rotate my wrist from "natural" and so this angle is perfect.

I am hoping to find a replacement when my heavily used one dies, but they are currently $69/each which seems excessive.

The middle finger wheel mice also cause my hand to cramp with extended use.

My criteria:

- Ergonomic mouse
- Rotated angle for hand - not 0° or 90°, but a mix
- Low(er) cost
- Mouse wheel not with middle finger

Can be either wired/USB. It'd be nice if it had a forward/backward button since those are great.

Comment: To clarify, you want the scroll wheel to be on the side? I'm slightly confused by what you said because traditional scroll wheels are usually used with the pointer finger and not the middle finger.

Comment: @Adam: really?  I've never used my index finger, always middle finger.

Comment: I'd guess which finger to use to scroll might be influenced by the mouse size, among other things.

Comment: I use a [Logitech MX master](https://secure.logitech.com/en-us/product/mx-master) which has a thumb scroll wheel. It defaults to horizontal scrolling but can be reconfigured within the software that comes with it. Unfortuenatly, it doesn't meet your cost criterion. I suggest you add it to a watch list it case it goes on sale anytime soon. It is of a high quality, and it helped with my wrist pain

Answer (score 6):

I've been using [Logitech G700s](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g700s-rechargeable-wireless-gaming-mouse) for two years and I can recommend it as both ergonomic and reliable.

- Ergonomic mouse — sure, it is.
- Rotated angle for hand - not 0° or 90°, but a mix — yes, looks like about 20°
- Low(er) cost — usually $100, but today Logitech sells it for $50, making it a low(er) cost mouse. Have no idea of how long the sale will last.
- Mouse wheel not with middle finger — it's with the index finger.
- Can be either wired/USB — both USB wire (can be unplugged) and wireless (Logitech reciever, not Bluetooth).
- forward/backward button — 8 extra customizable buttons (4 on thumb, 3 on index, 1 for mode switching) and wheel tilt. I actually have a pair of buttons for forward and backward and another pair for scrolling desktops on OS X.